# Centered animation is consistently off-center

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I've been struggling with this for the past few days, so help would be greatly appreciated. I have a Title with a line (hr element) right below it. I'm trying to have a div centered in the hr that grows and shrinks. However, when the css3 animation is applied it causes the div to be displaced down and to the right, as if the div's top-left point (which I think is (0,0)) is set to be where the middle was.

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLjsut5r/2/) to illustrate what I mean.

Here's my html:

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>Center</h1>

    <div id="action-bar">
        <hr class="center-line" />
        <div class="circle animation"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my css:

```
div#header {
    color: #000;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

div#header h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

/* the line beneath h1 */
 div #action-bar {
    margin: 25px 0;
    position: relative;
}

div.circle {
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    background: #000;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
}

div.circle:hover {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    background: #000;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
}

hr.center-line {
    border: 0;
    height: .25em;
    background: #000;
}

/* animation */
 @keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}

.animation {
    animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite normal none;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite normal none;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Can anybody point be in the right direction? I'm looking for a pure-css solution if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add negative margin to your `circle` element, half of it's `width` and `height`:

```
div.circle {
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    background: #000;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
}

div.circle:hover {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    margin-left: -1em;
    margin-top: -1em;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aLjsut5r/3/).

Comment: Ah, that did it. Guess it was a case of staring at it too long... Thanks much!

Comment: Any idea why the animation was adding a margin?

Comment: The margin isn't for animation, when you set `top` and `left` to `50%`, the top left corner of element, point `(0, 0)`, will be positioned at point `(50%, 50%)` (which is not exactly the center). You want the center of element in that point, then you should use negative margin to move the element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a smooth pulsing option.
http://jsfiddle.net/aLjsut5r/4/

```
/* animation */
@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(.8);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(.8);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
.animation {
    animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite normal none;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite normal none;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.pulsing {
    border: 3px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    left:20px;
    top:214px;
    -webkit-animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
    opacity: 0.0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
    0% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5); opacity: 0.5;}
    50% {opacity: 1.0;}
    100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2); opacity: 0.5;}
}
```

Comment: This answer wasn't really relevant to what I was asking...but thanks.

Comment: Eh, you were looking for a smoother animation on your "circle" class, so I just gave you an option.